# Subsequences terms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it necessary to be subsequence a part of the original sequence according to its definition, in other word must all terms of subsequence be terms of the original sequence?

Comment: Yes, by definition that is true.

Comment: Could you give a convergent subsequence of sin(n) plz?

Comment: [1,3,22,333...](https://oeis.org/A002485)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507823/subsequence-of-sin-n