# Increasing integer sequence $a_n$ so $\sin(a_n)\to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi, integer-sequences

I am looking for a (simple) formula for an increasing integer sequence $a_n$ such that $$\sin(a_n)\to 0.$$

Of course such a sequence exists, but I am hoping for a simple formula for such a sequence that I could show my students.

The context is the following: I wrote $a_n=\sin(n)$ on the board and my students confidently declared that it wasn't convergent. Fair enough...so I wrote $b_n=\sin(n^2)$ on the board. Again, they were confident it wasn't convergent. I explained to them that they had the tools to show $a_n$ was not convergent, but showing $b_n$ was not convergent would take a lot more work and wasn't at all obvious. So, I'm hoping for a counterexample to show them that it *really* isn't obvious whether a sequence $\sin(q_n)$ converges as $n\to\infty$. (A simple sequence where the answer is unknown by researchers would also be interesting.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Of course, $\pi n$ is not an integer.  The other obvious one, $a_n = 0$ is not increasing.

Comment: It is not clear from your phrasing whether you think $\sin n^2$ is convergent or not. "but showing bn
 was convergent would take a lot more work and wasn't at all obvious."

Comment: It is "not at all obvious" indeed! [it is false](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846791).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subsequence of $\sin n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507823/subsequence-of-sin-n)

Comment: @coffeemath, Anne Bauval, thank you for pointing out the error. I meant to say that showing b_n was *not* convergent took more work.

Comment: Why do you think that there exist an simple formula for such sequence?

Comment: What is needed can be shown also using the theory of Farey sequences and the fact that $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: @DiegoSantos I don't know it for a fact, and "simple" is subjective, but formulas like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Brouncker,_2nd_Viscount_Brouncker#Brouncker's_formula exist, which makes me guess there's a satisfying answer out there somewhere.

Comment: Not integers, but will rational multiples of $\pi$ work? If so, then students should readily see that $a_n = (\pi/2)(1-2^n)$ is increasing, but also should see that it $\sin(a_n)$ converges to $0$. OTOH, if you need $a_n$ to not converge... that's a bit harder.

Comment: @EricSnyder - not much harder. Just add $2\pi n$. @ Jason Siefken - You can indeed use continued fractions to find approximations to $\pi$ allowing you to use the denominators as your sequence. But your students are not going to find that sequence - no matter how much you try to pretty it up - to be "simple".

Comment: @PaulSinclair Exactly! That's why I asked the question :-) I am not aware of a "nice" formula for those denominators.